# parse json data with spark 2.3

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following json data :

```
{
  "3200": {
    "id": "3200",
    "value": [
      "cat",
      "dog"
    ]
  },
  "2000": {
    "id": "2000",
    "value": [
      "bird"
    ]
  },
  "2500": {
    "id": "2500",
    "value": [
      "kitty"
    ]
  },
  "3650": {
     "id": "3650",
      "value": [
      "horse"
    ]
  }
}
```

the schema of this data , with printSchema utilty after we load the data with spark is as follows:

```
    root
 |-- 3200: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- 2000: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- 2500: struct (nullable = true)
 |     |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- 3650: struct (nullable = true)
 |   |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

and I want to get the following dataframe

```
id    value

 3200  cat
 2000  bird
 2500  kitty
 3200  dog
 3650  horse
```

How can I do the parsing to get this expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stack()` function to transpose the dataframe then extract `key` field and explode `value` field using `explode_outer` function.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

import spark.implicits._

val jsonData = """{
                   |  "3200": {
                   |    "id": "3200",
                   |    "value": [
                   |      "cat",
                   |      "dog"
                   |    ]
                   |  },
                   |  "2000": {
                   |    "id": "2000",
                   |    "value": [
                   |      "bird"
                   |    ]
                   |  },
                   |  "2500": {
                   |    "id": "2500",
                   |    "value": [
                   |      "kitty"
                   |    ]
                   |  },
                   |  "3650": {
                   |     "id": "3650",
                   |      "value": [
                   |      "horse"
                   |    ]
                   |  }
                   |}
                   |""".stripMargin

val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonData).toDS())

df.selectExpr("stack (4, *) key")
    .select(expr("key.id").as("key"),
      explode_outer(expr("key.value")).as("value"))
    .show(false)

+----+-----+
|key |value|
+----+-----+
|2000|bird |
|2500|kitty|
|3200|cat  |
|3200|dog  |
|3650|horse|
+----+-----+
```

Comment: could we have a alternative without hardcoding the 4 number

Comment: Use `df.columns.length`

Answer (score 1):

Using spark-sql

Dataframe step (same as in Mohana's answer)

```
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonData).toDS())
```

Build a temp view

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

Result:

```
val cols_k = df.columns.map( x => s"`${x}`.id" ).mkString(",")
val cols_v = df.columns.map( x => s"`${x}`.value" ).mkString(",")
spark.sql(s""" 
with t1 ( select map_from_arrays(array(${cols_k}),array(${cols_v})) s from df ),
     t2 ( select explode(s) (key,value) from t1 )
     select key, explode(value) value from t2

""").show(false)

+----+-----+
|key |value|
+----+-----+
|2000|bird |
|2500|kitty|
|3200|cat  |
|3200|dog  |
|3650|horse|
+----+-----+
```

Comment: could you please write it in scala or python